# Change the color of the keyboard in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

When people select the light theme the keyboard changes to a light color. Unfortunately this doesn't contrast very well with the branding in the app I'm making. I'm not sure if we can do this but is it possible to change the background and foreground of the keyboard or is this dependent on what theme the user has selected?

I originally thought it wasn't possible but with Mango we can change the system tray and app bar. Seems like the keyboard could be modified also.

Comment: Sometimes when in the light theme my app will show a dark keyboard.  Haven't quite figured out when - but it may have to do with overriding system tray or app bar or background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as confirmed in [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/92040/551776.aspx#551776). The creator of that post has submitted a request here which you can [vote on](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1719389-can-set-custom-theme?ref=title) if you like.

Comment: I didn't even know they had this site. Cool.

Comment: Yup :) They also have one for users rather than developers: http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do... you can create a custom keyboard http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

But thats alot of work....

Answer (score 0):

It's somehow possible. When using Jeff Wilcox PhoneThemeManager and forcing LightTheme when it's dark, keyboard color is also changed.